# Measuring basin length in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10 to compute Morphometric parameters for 2 catchments. I have already calculated the Linear parameters, (stream order,stream length, Bifurcation ratio) I have also calculated some of the Aerial parameters ( drainage density, drainage texture, stream frequency ) I am currently calculating the Form factor and Enlongation ratio. I have calculated the Area of the basin. The next thing to do is calculate the Basin length. That is where i am stuck.

Is there a way to get it in ArcMap?

Or is basin length same as flow length?

What method or measure can i use to determine the length of the basin?

Comment: What do you mean by basin length? Do you mean perimeter? Or what?

Comment: I am calculating some morphometric parameters and i am at the point where i want to calculate the form factor for a catchment i.e AREA/BASIN LENGHT.

Comment: Please add any detail to your question to make it clear, what have you tried so far, and where did you stuck, so that it can help the community to answer your question.

Comment: As stated before i am computing Morphometric parameters for 2 catchments. I have already calculated the Linear parameters, (stream order,stream length, Bifurcation ratio) I have also calculated some of the Aerial parameters ( drainage density, drainage texture, stream frequency ) I am on the Form factor and Enlongation ratio. I have calculated the Area of the basin. The next thing to do is calculate the Basin length. That is where i am stuck.....Is there a way to get it in arc map ? or is basin length same as flow length?

Comment: You  can add all the information you wrote in the comment to the question  by pressing the edit button located under the question, and do not forget to add the picture because we don't see any picture.

Comment: Thanks to all that contributed :   The basin
length can be  measured using the measure tool in ArcGIS

Comment: How have you calculated length of streams for each sub basins?